# Using C# can I communicate with webpages and local desktop programs?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to C# and Microsoft Visual Studio, so, with that in mind, I am teaching myself and have started a project (excuse my lack of vocabulary). What I have so far is a WPF project that looks good but offers zero functionality. The general functionality I envision is this:

1. The Main Window has multiple buttons which navigate to multiple pages. (Achieved this already)
2. On each page navigated to, I want to display information from a website. (?)
3. Using the web information, I want control another program on the desktop. (?)

Are points (2) and (3) possible using C#?

Let me illustrate the scenario. A person submits information (username) into a website. That website contacts a server and sends back data about that person/username. The website then stores this data and usernames on a list visible to the users. There are five different lists and five navigable xaml pages via the main window on the program. I want to display each list on each page. Using the data found on the website and now my program, I want to send a command to a program/script running on the desktop and have it perform an action (type the usernames somewhere using AutoHotKey and AutoScriptWriter, which is essentially updating a special notepad file).

The answers I am looking for are not "this is how you do specifically what you're asking" but rather "Use these tools/features in C# and start there". If what I want from this program is possible, I have these follow up questions:

1. The information submitted to that website would be constant, so would the web information viewed through the program be updated/refreshed in real-time?
2. Would creating an entirely new website to work with the program be more beneficial than using an existing website and scraping information from it?
3. Can a program communicate with another program on a local virtual desktop via Oracle VirtualBox?
4. If someone used this program on their computer, could they command the program/script on my computer via the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answers to your various questions:

1. Is not a question...
2. Websites are just user interfaces sitting on top of logic defined on a webserver - if you can interact with the logic (i.e. a webservice) instead of with the raw UI layer (which is HTML) you should rather do that. You can find a control which will render HTML information but this is unlikely to be the best approach for what you want to do.
3. Yes, through COMInterop with the Windows Shell - quite an advanced topic and I hope you understand Windows SDK, memory management and unmanaged, unsafe pointer-based code quite well.

Follow-up questions:

1. I don't understand the question - you're submitting information constantly or the information you're submitting is always the same? You would need to trigger the refresh of the web information (i.e. request the particular page) when you want a refreshed rendering of the webpage.
2. Most beneficial would not be using the user interface at all (webpage) and establishing a link to the logic layer instead and requesting the data directly via a web service - it gives you the most control in your WPF application.
3. Yes, but again, very advanced stuff - it's not simple or easy and comes with a host of challenges such as local security and automation APIs for VirtualBox.
4. Doubtful unless you wrote the code to be internet-enabled which again, is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation correctly, you can use the `WebClient` class to communicate with your web server and use the returned string by it to generate the content.

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Headers.Add("HTTP Header", "Header Value");
web.Headers.Add("POST Data Header", "POST Data Value");
string response = web.DownloadString(new Uri("https://www.myserver.net/mypage"));
// Implement your processing on response variable here to generate and present data to the user.
```

And you can use the `StandardOutput` of the `Process` class to get the output of any programs on the local machine.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Path\to\my\executable.exe";
proc.Start();
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
// Start the process...
proc.Start();
// Retrieve the output...
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```